# Is there any similar class available in C++ and Java as "pyautogui"?

Tags: java, c++, python-3.x, pyautogui

Python has a class named **"pyautogui"** to perform some task automatically on system interfere(Control mouse and keyboard strokes by method of that class). Is there any similar class available in C++ and Java? Help me out dudes by writing down names of this class. Thanks in advance, ❤.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question: Is there any similar class available in Java?
Answer: Yes.

More info: Read the java documentation of java.awt.Robot